# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'slice' in using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, slice

I have column title (`genre`). I try to get first element by using many way slicing split and try to using another method but I have this message:

```
for x in df['genres']:
    c = tuple(x).slice(0, x.find('|'))
    print (c)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'slice'
```

`genre` has values like this (`Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller`) for ten thousand rows.

Comment: So are you trying to get the first item (e.g. `Action`)?

Answer (score 1):

`tuple` just doesn't have `slice`. Try using `pandas.Series.str.split` instead:

```
# Sample data
                                              genres
0      Thriller|Action|Adventure|Adventure|Adventure
1  Science Fiction|Adventure|Science Fiction|Adve...
2  Science Fiction|Thriller|Science Fiction|Thril...
3  Adventure|Thriller|Science Fiction|Action|Thri...
4        Action|Adventure|Adventure|Adventure|Action

df["genres"].str.split("|").str[0]
```

Output:

```
0           Thriller
1    Science Fiction
2    Science Fiction
3          Adventure
4             Action
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

Explain:

- `df["genres"].str.split("|")`: splits each element in `df["genres"]` with the given `sep`. This will yield `list`s of separated items in each row.
- `str[0]`: selects the first item of lists from each row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `tuple` for this.

Try this:

```
for x in df['genres']:
    c = x.split('|')[0]
    print(c)
```